# Windows Store app is currently not available in Windows Store

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-10, windows-store, windows-8.1-universal

I uploaded one app called 'Smartflow' to the Windows Store and it passed all the certification and published in Windows Store. But when I navigate to Windows Store through the [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/smartflow/9nblggh3645b#app-details) it says `Smartflow is currently not available.`

I don't have any idea on this. Please suggest me. Thanks

[image]

Comment: I see the link to get the app.  Are you sure the app is available for the computers language?

Comment: Hi @Ken Tucker I didn't get it. Computers language? Thanks!

Comment: sorry should have said region.  For example you released it for En-US and am trying to get the app in a computer with a regional setting of EN-UK where it is not available

Comment: I released it in en-US language. And my computer has regional setting to en-US too. Are there any other factors that might affect the availability of app?

Comment: i clicked on the link on the web page and get the same message.  I do see that is says the app needs hardware your device doesn't have under ratings and reviews.. Do you see the same?

Comment: what version of windows 10 does your app target?  It is in the project properties

Comment: In the application manifest edit with the xml editor is there anything in the targetdevicefamily?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn986903.aspx

Comment: I looked into the app manifest and there is nothing related to targetdevicefamily. And also I looked into the app project properties and it targets to Windows 8.1 only. My requirement is that the app must be available for both Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 users.

Comment: Hi @Ken Tucker, There was some minor mistake while publishing to windows store. I haven't selected all countries so it not available to download for US region. I updated and made it available to all countries and now it is available to all users around the world. Thanks for effort. Really appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my regional settings, I should be able to see all en-US apps. I can verify that the Smartflow app does appear to me in the Windows Store. I tried the link you provided in a browser, and also tried a quick search from the Windows Store app.

Below is a screenshot of my screen before downloading the app. I was then able to download and launch the app with no issues. FYI, I am running Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1511 (OS Build 10586.29) as of Dec 28, 2015.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I updated my app information in Dashboard and made it available to all countries.

Comment: Cool, if you found my response and screenshot useful, please mark it as answer. Thanks and have a Happy New Year! :)